# Can't get all git commit message in tfs build

Tags: git, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I'm building a CI build and want to get the git commit message from developers in order to parse it in my script.

I've added a batch command-line step and pass `$(BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE)` in the Argument edit box but I just not getting all the commit message.

The message is multi-line:

> PR 231: ALGCQ-79343 Merge release-rsna to develop
>
> - PR 225: Merge layout_poc_2 to release-rsna
> - Add icons for RSNA
> - bug fix: dropdowns did not work on iPad.
> - remove direct reference to material design for PMA strip report/bookmark icons.
> - puzzlehead bugfix for RSNA ...

The text includes CRLF because it's an automatic message from the pull-request and what I get in the script is just the first 2 lines.

Because of that it also break the rest of the argument list which not being passed to the script.

I also tried to get the the message from environment variable in powershell script and got the same.

Is there any character lenth I dont know of?
Doest someone know a way the get the full commit message and send it to a script?

Comment: Are you able to get all git commit message in your script locally? Only in TFS build you can't get all git commit message? How's your script like? You may try REST API for Git commits: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits#by-the-committer

Comment: @Cece-MSFT I get the same not fully commit message inside the script. IThe script is just "Write-Host $Build.SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE". do you know about a length limitation?

Comment: What's the result with "Write-Host $env:Build_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE" command?

Comment: I get 100 characters from the etire message, which is much longer. I rewrite the script and I dont sent the commit message anymore but I get it from the local git on the CI machine with repo module.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> The comment of the commit or changeset for the triggering repo. We truncate the message to the first line or 200 characters, whichever is shorter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511#build-variables-devops-services

If you need the full message I suspect you'll need to run this git command in case you have the repo checked out on the agent.

```
git log --format=%B -n 1 <commit>
```

Or use the REST API to get the details for the commit.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}?api-version=6.0
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511